# hibernate selects on relation one to many

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, entity

I am developing a jee project using eclispe sts and maven

I have a relation with category parent of article, 
after adding some article with correct parents id (checked in the database) when I select the list of all articles with their category I obtain a reference to the entity as follows com.stock.mvc.entities.Category@b01648

any idea ?

this is the relation category article in the entity article

```
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "idCategory")  
  private Category category;
```

and the relation article category in the entity category

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy ="category")
  private List<Article> articles;
```

this is the table of articles in the view article.jsp

```
<td>${article.getCodeArticle() }</td>                
<td>${article.getDesignation() }</td>                
<td>${article.getPrixUnitaireHt() }</td>                 
<td>${article.getTauxTva() }</td>                
<td>${article.getPrixUnitaireTTC() }</td>                
<td>${article.getCategory() }</td>
```

the last line (${article.getCategory() }) displays the following message instead of the category id com.stock.mvc.entities.Category@b01648

Comment: Any idea about what? What is the question/problem?

Comment: how to select the category name from the entity Category using jstl

Comment: `${category.name}`? You're aware that you haven't posted any single line of code, right? We can't see your code if you don't post it. We can't know what you want to do if you don't say.

Comment: Post everything you need to post in the question. Not in comments.

Comment: Why would it display the category ID? You're asking to display the category object, not the category ID. If you want to display the category ID, then do it: ${article.category.id}.

Comment: right I fixed it via the getter

Comment: The JSP EL does not access fields. It accesses public properties, i.e. getters. So `${article.getCategory().getId() }` is just an unnecessarily verbose and less readable version of `${article.category.id}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your entities because you havent posted here.

But one thing which is visible here is you are accessing values using getters which is wrong way.Instead you can access values by field names like below.

```
<td>${article.category}</td>
```

Note : Ensure that if an object is Collection then you need to iterate it.

You are getting `com.stock.mvc.entities.Category@b01648` because this is category object, so you can access its field by using `. dot` operator like below.

```
 <td>${category.name}</td>
```

Comment: fields are private that why I am using getters and setters to access them

Comment: no need to use like that...spring expression language does that for you...use like i suggested in answer..it will work